# mlogit : using varying alternatives for mlogit in R

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to use varying alternatives for each person. However not able to get it working. If I make the alternatives same for each person, it works fine. How to make it varying and work.

Data :

```
> dput( df1 )
structure(list(Choice = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), A = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
0L), C = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L), F = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L), Alternative = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code :

```
model = mlogit( Choice ~ B + C + D + E + F | 0, data = df1, 
               
                alt.levels = unique( df1$Alternative ), 
               
               shape = "long")
```

Error

```
Error in dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index = dfa$drop.index,  : 
  the data must be balanced in order to use the levels argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `mlogit` with an explicit ID variable denoting which participant made the choice. It can't infer them from the `data.frame` you've provided.

I'm assuming in your reproducible example that the alternatives in rows running sequentially from [1 - 4] or [1 - 3] represent the choice sets presented to a unique individual. If so, then you can fit a model like so:

```r
library(mlogit)

# Explicitly create an ID variable
df1$ID <- rep(1:12, times = c(rep(4, 2), rep(3, 10)))

#Convert to dfidx data
dfx1 <- mlogit.data(df1, 
                    shape = "long", 
                    choice = "Choice",
                    id.var = "ID")

# Fit a model
m0 <- mlogit(Choice ~ B + C + D + E + F | 0, 
             data = dfx1)
```